# REST login with Django social_auth

Tags: django, rest, django-piston, django-socialauth

I've been asked to provide a "Login with Facebook" functionality to an iOS app I am creating.
The app connects to a REST api created with Piston, the web application is created with Django and uses social_auth. The application also has a Facebook login.

My thought was to create a service 'FBLogin' providing just the Facebook profile UID (separate FB login procedure on iPhone to get the ID). Using the SocialAuth models I can query the DB with uid and provider to fetch the user... but how can i use the authentication mechanism to get this user instance authenticated?

Any ideas on getting this right? 
This just doesn't feel good  ... getting the user instance authenticated is a pain...

The username password authentication is already implemented ... without a problem.

Btw, don't have django experience ... do have a lot of other development experience so understanding python and django isn't that hard :)

Tx
Y

Comment: which one are we talking about? https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth

Comment: https://github.com/agiliq/Django-Socialauth ?

Comment: https://github.com/omab/django-social-auth :-)
I do have a satisfactory solution for now but still want to know how to handle this kind of authentication via REST.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't really seem to be documented anywhere, but you can do this in your REST handler:

```
from social_auth.backends.pipeline.social import associate_user
from social_auth.backends.facebook import FacebookBackend
from social_auth.models import UserSocialAuth
myextra_data = {
    'access_token' : 'jfkdlfsdgeyejfghfdsjdfpoweipuo',
    'id' : 123456789,
}
usa, created = UserSocialAuth.objects.get_or_create(provider = 'facebook',
                                                      uid=123456789)
usa.user = user
usa.extra_data = myextra_data
usa.save()
if created:
    associate_user(backend=FacebookBackend, user=user, uid=usa.uid)
```

These get pretty vendor-specific in terms of how data gets formatted in `extra_data` so YMMV